# Windows 8.1 puTTY empty window

Tags: putty, windows-8.1

first post here.

I just got started on a windows 8.1 machine.  I downloaded putty and ran the installer, but when I attempt to connect to anything, I just get an empty window. Attached is an image to clarify.

I tried a few other clients and got the same problem, although filezilla seems to work fine for ftp.

Does anyone know what might cause this problem?

Thanks,

Tracy

(PS responses in super noob language would be appreciated. I am pretty new to these things.)

update:
Looks like it won't let me add images because I don't have enough clout yet.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same hosts using Putty from a different machine?  PS I do not see an attached image in your post.

Comment: Yes, I can connect just fine from other computers. I can't add an image because I don't have reputation here. Usually upon opening the window, I get a "login as" prompt, however now It just remains empty and unresponsive, just the cursor sitting in the upper left with no text or prompt.

Comment: Any chance that you are accidentally using the default connection type, which is Telnet, when you should be using SSH?

Comment: I believe that my install defaulted at SSH, but either way the radio for SSH is currently selected.

Comment: The putty eventlog might help (see http://malektips.com/putty-diagnose-event-log.html).  Also try running it in compatibility mode (see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows).

Comment: Hmm just tried compatibility mode, didn't seem to work. Event log reads 

2014-01-06 12:57:58 Looking up host "204.232.152.59"
2014-01-06 12:57:58 Connecting to 204.232.152.59 port 22
2014-01-06 12:57:58 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63

Comment: Disable the local firewall temporarily and re-test.  Try another SSH/telnet client on the same machine, or simply telnet directly to port 22 on the target to see if you can connect.  You need to understand if your networking is the issue, or if putty itself is the issue.  Does the remote server have any kind of ingress source IP checking (for example AWS Security Groups) that are blocking your IP?  Is there a local firewall blocking outbound SSH?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found that the Norton Anti-virus was controlling my firewall and blocking it. With Norton disabled, I was able to get through! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

check that your device is not IP-access restricted. It would allow connections from existing devices, but not the new.